# how to get rspec controller test to a non-restful endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I am trying to test an endpoint that is not one of the restfuls provided in rails, (`i.e: #index, #new, #edit, #update, #create, #destroy`)

In my `routes.rb` file:

```
get 'hospitals/:id/doctors' => 'hospitals#our_doctors'
```

and from inside my `hospitals_controller_spec.rb` file:

```
describe "GET #our_doctors" do
  before do
    get :our_doctors
  end
end
```

but I'm having the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"our_doctors", :controller=>"hospitals"}
```

how can I go about getting my spec to follow the required route?

I have also tried to call it as:

```
get "/hospitals/#{@hospital.id}/doctors"
```

but getting following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/hospitals/1/doctors", :controller=>"hospitals"}
```

all helps are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about naming your route like this:

```
get 'hospitals/:id/doctors' => 'hospitals#our_doctors', as: :our_doctors
```

If that doesn't work you can specify the route your spec uses like this:

```
describe "GET #our_doctors" do
  before do
    get :our_doctors, use_route: :our_doctors
  end
end
```

Comment: oh, thanks, `get 'hospitals/:id/doctors' => 'hospitals#our_doctors', as: :our_doctors` worked. and could you explain the other one below it? (`get :our_doctors, use_route: :our_doctors`) thanks.

Comment: No probs. Yeah sure if your controller spec can't automatically find your request (get :our_doctors) you can give it a hint with use_route

Answer (score 0):

The above solution of using the use_route is a temporary one as you might get a deprecation warning(depending on your rspec-rails version). Below is an excerpt of that warning when I tried to use that method:

...Passing the `use_route` option in functional tests are deprecated. Support for this option in the `process` method (and the related `get`, `head`, `post`, `patch`, `put` and `delete` helpers) will be removed in the next version without replacement. Functional tests are essentially unit tests for controllers and they should not require knowledge to how the application's routes are configured. Instead, you should explicitly pass the appropriate params to the `process` method...

So as suggested, for posterity I would in your case do the following to avoid any errors for unsupported/deprecated syntax:

```
get :our_doctors, id: [id_of_hospital]
```

NOTE: correct me if i'm wrong but the above assumes that you want to render all doctors under a particular hospital.

In general, for I would advise for all non-RESTful collection routes test as follows:

```
get :action, id: [id_of_resource]
```

and that should be fine. Hope that was helpful.